# Importance of universal enveloping algebras and Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, lie-algebras

Let $L$ denote a Lie algebra and $U(L)$ denote its universal enveloping algebra. I am trying to see why universal enveloping algebra and PBW theorem are important. Precisely:

> 1. Given any $L$-module $V$ universal property of $U(L)$ says that $V$ is an $U(L)$-module. So what?
> 2. Recall that PBW theorem states that sym$(L) \cong$ gr$(U(L))$. Why is this theorem useful?

I'll be obliged if someone can explain about above things in detail.

Comment: Have you seen Verma modules?

Comment: 1.) So $L$-modules correspond to $U(L)$-modules, hence are $R$-modules forming an abelian category.  2.) PBW has a lot of other applications, including estimates on the minimal degree of faithful Lie algebra modules (which has geometric implications).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft,Unfortunately not.Is there any other way to see usefulness?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Since i have just started learning about $U(L)$ and PBW theorem,so i dont understand whatever you've written.Could you please explain the first point a bit more? I dont understand the $2$nd point at all.

Comment: Just continue learning about Lie algebra and you will see that the enveloping algebra and the PBW theorem show up in many places.